# TweepError attribute error when using Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am getting an:

> AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'TweepError'.

Here is my relevant code in Python:

```py
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    msg = 'Query failed when max_id equaled {0}: {1}'.format(max_id, e)
    logging.error(msg)
```

My other code with tweepy is working so I'm sure I've installed it correctly, and it seems that tweep error is included in the current documentation.

Answer (score 4):

except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:

Answer (score 0):

The correct exception is `tweepy.errors.TweepError`, so change that line to:

```
except tweepy.errors.TweepError as e:
```

in older versions of Tweepy, it was previously:

```
except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
```

Comment: There may be a typo in the above answer, i am getting the same error unless i write 'errors' except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e

Comment: @GGiorgio Since I wrote this answer, Tweepy have changed from placing all exceptions under `tweepy.error` to `tweepy.errors`. I'll update my answer to reflect this new change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions above but as of 24th of May, this one works for me:

```py
except AttributeError:
```

Answer (score -2):

It appears that you are encountering an AttributeError while handling exceptions in your Python code that involves the Tweepy library. The error message indicates that the module 'tweepy' does not possess an attribute named 'TweepError'. To address this issue, it's important to make a small modification to your code.

The Tweepy library has undergone certain updates, resulting in changes to its exception handling attributes. Instead of using tweepy.TweepError, you should now use tweepy.errors.TweepyException to catch exceptions related to Tweepy operations.
Here's how your code snippet should be adjusted accordingly:

```
import tweepy
import logging

# Your code

try:
    # Your Tweepy operation here
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
    msg = 'Query failed when max_id equaled {0}: {1}'.format(max_id, e)
    logging.error(msg)
```

By making this modification, you'll be using the appropriate exception attribute for the Tweepy library, and your code should function as expected.

Remember to ensure that you have the latest version of the Tweepy library installed, as using the correct attribute is dependent on the version you are using. Upgrading to the latest version will provide you with the most up-to-date exception attributes and features.

If you encounter any further issues or have additional questions, feel free to ask for assistance.
Please make sure to replace 'Your code' with the actual code snippet you're working with, and adapt the response as needed to match the specific situation.